# Can I alias the empty string?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

In bash, can you alias a null command to something? 
In other words, recognize that the user has pressed
just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key at the shell prompt? 
For example, if you want to clear the screen
with a blank shell entry,
how do you alias the <kbd>Enter</kbd> to the `clear` command?

Comment: Alias name must have a least one letter. Try `alias c='clear'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s how to (effectively) alias an empty command to something:

Put the following into your `.bashrc`:

```
command1()
{
    if [ "$BASH_COMMAND" != command2 ]
    then
        command_flag=1
    fi
    return 0
}
trap command1 debug
command2()
{
    if [ ! "$command_flag" ]
    then
        echo "clear"                            # Put whatever command(s) you want here.
    fi
    command_flag=
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=command2
```

If necessary, replace `command1` and `command2` consistently
with words that you’re less likely to type randomly.

- `trap command1 debug` will cause the `command1` function to be executed
  every time you (the user) type a command.

  - If the most recent command to be executed was not `command2`,
    `command1` will set `command_flag`.
- Assigning `command2` to `PROMPT_COMMAND`
  will cause `command2` to be executed
  whenever the shell is about to issue a prompt.

  - If `command_flag` has a non-blank value,
    that means `command1` was just executed,
    which means the user just ran a command. 
    In this case, do nothing.
  - If `command_flag` does *not* have a non-blank value,
    that means the user just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
    In this case, do what you want to do (e.g., clear the screen).
  - In either case, set `command_flag` to blank,
    so everything will work on the next cycle.

Note: I’m pretty sure that this is bash-specific
(i.e., not supported by POSIX).

This answer was basically copied from my answer
to [Adding vertical space after command in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197601/23408#197802). 
See also [tell if last command was empty in PROMPT_COMMAND](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226909/23408)
for other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: `Ctrl-l` will clear the screen without printing a character or pressing enter. This is probably the closest you'll get to your desired functionality. You can make a command run before or after every command, or you can make an alias for a single character. You cannot alias the empty string.

Aliases are not necessarily designed to be the whole thing entered on a line.

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

is a good example of this. You can do `ll /path/to/other/dir` and get results.

**All an alias does is literally change the first word(s) typed on the command line to the value to you gave it**

The only requirement for an alias to work is that it must be followed a non-printing character (space/tab/newline). In our case, `ll` by itself is valid, but `ll-/mypath/` isn't, because it is possible (and frequently done) to alias a few characters that can be the start of another command (i.e., `alias gi='git init'` can only resolve exactly `gi`, not `git`, which is what most people want and expect).

It isn't possible to alias something to the empty string, since that would be at the start of *every* command line entry.

If you want a command to run every time, you can use `PS0` (assuming a recent-enough version of bash) to run something before every command or `PROMPT_COMMAND` to run something after every command. For example:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo $?'
```

would echo the return value of the command you ran after every command you run.

Bash does not have a good way of completing an action if and only if you've entered an empty line on the command line. Bash is not whitespace sensitive in this way.

Comment: Thanks @jeremysprofile that was quite informative. So there is no way to test the last bash command run in PROMPT_COMMAND for example?

Comment: You can test the last command run. If you're really looking for some esoteric stuff, @Scott's answer does exactly what you asked (I didn't know that was possible).

Comment: My only real grievance with command-l is it doesn’t print a prompt.

Comment: When I do `ctrl-l`, the only thing at the top of my terminal is my prompt. What do you see?

Comment: This *can* be handled by bash; specifically, by bash’s “readline” function.  If I type `bind -P | grep clear`, I get `clear-screen can be found on "\C-l".`, which says that Ctrl+L (`C-l`) is bound to the “clear-screen” function.  What do you get when you issue that `bind | grep` command?  If you don’t have the Ctrl+L key bound, it’s possible that your terminal is handling the keystroke without telling bash (so bash doesn’t know to re-issue the prompt).

Comment: @Scott, my bad, it's `PS0`. I'll edit the post.